# Storage text input and displays them on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a text input where users can type anything, after submitting I want that text to be stored and displayed on a Page, and stay there, I don't want it to disappear after refreshing. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<input id="NewPostField" type="text" value="Some text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add new post</button>
<div id="Posts"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var NewPostField = document.getElementById("NewPostField");
  var newPost = document.createElement("p");
  newPost.innerHTML = NewPostField.value;
  var Posts = document.getElementById("Posts");
  Posts.appendChild(newPost);
}
```

I know about `localStorage` and `Cookies`, but I need help with getting it to work

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `localStorage` or cookies. Give google a second chance.

Comment: I did and I read all about it, but I dont know how to get it working, thats the problem

Comment: You read “all about it”? There are a lot of examples online.

Comment: see here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I already read it, that was first article I read, but im kinda new to JavaScript and Im having difficulty to get this thing working, thanks for help tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use PHP `$_SESSION`, or JS `localStorage`, or cookies..

**There is a lot of ways to store datas**, on client or server side.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt mean you guys to code it for me, im just new to JavaScript and I was looking for some working examples on my code, I do understand everything and already tried Cookies and LocalStorage, but the problem is that I cant get it working ON my example.

Comment: Nice to hear this :) Can you be more precise on what difficulties you're facing when using localStorage or cookies ? I'll help you as much as I can

Comment: I was having trouble to storage output text, And I tried a lot of examples but theres none example on outputting the text from input form, Pnadalini’s code helped me, Ill figure out how to display multiple inputs

Answer (score 1):

I've made a simple change on your js code that you can try to start learning more about [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
function myFunction() {
  var NewPostField = document.getElementById("NewPostField");
  var newPost = document.createElement("p");

  localStorage.setItem('text', NewPostField.value);
  newPost.innerHTML = NewPostField.value;

  var Posts = document.getElementById("Posts");
  Posts.appendChild(newPost);
}

(function() {
  const previousText = localStorage.getItem('text');
  if (previousText) {
    var NewPostField = document.getElementById("NewPostField");
    NewPostField.value = previousText;

    myFunction();
  }
})();
```

As you can see when the page loads, it will excecute the second method, which will set get the saved data on your localstorage and load it in the page, in the input and it will also create the `<p>` tag to display that text in your page like you did.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how persistent you want the data to be. If you just want it to stay there as long as the page is open, use sessionStorage. MDN even has a working code example for *almost* exactly what you've requested:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage#saving_text_between_refreshes

Based on your code and the MDN article, you could try something like this:

```js
// Get the elements
const field = document.getElementById("NewPostField");
const button = document.getElementById("AddPost");
const posts = document.getElementById("Posts");

// Restore an autosave value if present
const savedPosts = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");
if (savedPosts) {
  // Restore the contents of the text field
  posts.innerHTML = savedPosts;
}

// Handle the button click
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Add the text to the list of posts
  const newPost = document.createElement('p');
  newPost.innerHTML = field.value;
  postDiv.append(newPost);
  // And save the results into the session storage object
  sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", posts.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<input id="NewPostField" type="text" value="Some text">
<button id="AddPost">Add new post</button>
<div id="Posts"></div>
```

Note, however, that the above is **VERY UNSAFE**, as the user could type effectively anything into the field, including scripts, and have it execute as soon as it's added. If you only want to allow text (not richtext), you should use textContent instead of innerHTML, but then you'll need to store things as an array. You'd do that like this:

```js
// post array
const postText = [];

// Get the elements
const field = document.getElementById("NewPostField");
const button = document.getElementById("AddPost");
const posts = document.getElementById("Posts");

// Add text to the list of posts
function addPost(text) {
  postText.push(text);
  const newPost = document.createElement('p');
  newPost.textContent = text;
  posts.append(newPost);
}

// Restore an autosave value if present
const savedPosts = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("autosave"));
if (savedPosts) {
  // Restore the contents of the text field
  for (let post of savedPosts) {
    addPost(post);
  }
}

// Handle the button click
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Add post to array and display div
  addPost(field.value);
  // Save the updated array into the session storage object
  sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", JSON.stringify(postText));
});
```

```html
<input id="NewPostField" type="text" value="Some text">
<button id="AddPost">Add new post</button>
<div id="Posts"></div>
```

Unfortunately the above can't be run due to browser cross-origin restrictions, but you can try locally on your page. You'll also see that I've used event listeners instead of onclick. This is because event listeners are more flexible and it keeps all the logic together in one place.

If you need the data to persist every time the user visits your site, use localStorage instead. You may also want to look at the newer [Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_API), however it will only work on secure (https) pages and extensions.